# How do you use onMouseOver with a Switch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, this, onmouseover

OnmouseOver of images #About, #Contact, or #Blog I would like to change the attribute depending on which link is mousedover using a switch statement. However, it does not work if I place the switch in a function, or try to give the switch a name. Here is what I have:

```
<g id="About" onmouseover="myFunction(this)"></g>
<g id="Contact" onmouseover="myFunction(this)"></g>
   <g id="Blog" onmouseover="myFunction(this)"></g>

<script type="text/javascript">


            switch myFunction (obj.id) {
    case About:
                    console.log (obj.id);
        break;
    case Contact:
                    console.log (obj.id);
        break;
    case Photos:

                    console.log (obj.id);
        break;
    case Videos:

                    console.log (obj.id);
        break;
    case Home:

             console.log (obj.id);
        break;
    case Online:

                    console.log (obj.id);
        break;
    case Blog:

                    console.log (obj.id);
}
```

My Inital test is as follows:

```
        function myFunction (obj) {

alert (obj.id);

            switch (obj.id) {
    case About:
                    console.log (obj.id);
        break;
    case Contact:
                    console.log (obj.id);
        break;
    case Photos:

                    console.log (obj.id);
        break;
    case Videos:

                    console.log (obj.id);
        break;
    case Home:

             console.log (obj.id);
        break;
    case Online:

                    console.log (obj.id);
        break;
    case Blog:

                    console.log (obj.id);
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cases should be strings unless you've assigned them as variables somewhere, eg "About" rather than About.

Comment: Thanks! I never used switches like this before, and didn't consider the fact the example was using numbers instead of strings, so I needed to add quotets.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make an actual function, not a switch that you thought was a function.

```
function myFunction(obj) {

}
```

Then add the switch inside the function:

```
switch (obj.id) {

}
```

Next put the cases inside the switch like you have done. And by the way, don't put spaces inbetween the open parens and the function name like you had for each

```
console.log (obj.id);
```

Hope it works. If it doesnt, comment why.

Comment: I had it as a function initially, that is why I mentioned in the original post that I'd tried putting it in a function. I have updated the comment to include that code. The alert works, and there are no errors, but the switch still wont.